# Spring MVC viewController haven't the same behavior depending on template engine

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, freemarker, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring MVC through Spring boot starters (1.3.2) and i saw a difference of behavior regarding which template engine i'm using.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        // template file 
        registry.addViewController("/index").setViewName("index");
        // static file
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login.html");
    }
}
```

If i used `Freemarker` as template engine, Spring mvc will take the file from `resources/static` for `/login` and in `resources/templates` for `/index`

Whereas, if i used `Thymeleaf` as template engine, Spring will take all the files (`login` and `index`) from `resources/templates`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this paths depends of application properties. By default:

```
#for freemaker
spring.freemarker.template-loader-path=classpath:/templates/

#for thymeleaf
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
```

Full list of common application properties you can find [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

View controller does not change behavior. When you entered url, Spring looking for method of Controller or ViewController, which has suitable request mapping. If method found, Spring invoke it. After that, controller's method returns view name as string, and Spring ask for special bean, named `ViewResolver`, to find view with this name.

*Since every template engine has own `ViewResolver`, and any `ViewResolver` has it's own setings (as I said above), they're looking for templates in different places.*

For example, you're using Thymeleaf and entered as url something like: `localhost:8080/index`. First, spring will find controller method or view-controller mapped with `index`. After that, controller will return string `index`. Spring will ask for Teamleaf view resolver to find this view. According to default settings, view resolver will add `classpath:/templates/` before view name, and `.html` after view name, and after that will try to open file with this name.

Comment: I don't override any properties. I'm questioning about the behavior of the viewController which changed when i change the template engine.